# how to update current logged user username

Tags: login, user-access, authentication

I need to keep in sync the username and the email of my users. I don't know if there is a better way so I have tried running this code right after the user updates his profile data:

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->update(
    $wpdb->users,
    array('user_login' => $email),
    array('ID' => $user->ID)
);
```

but this way the auth cookie becomes invalid and the user is logged out.

I have also tried forcing the creation of the auth cookie right after the update, like this:

```
wp_clear_auth_cookie();
$user = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id ); 
if( $user ) {
    wp_set_current_user( $user_id, $user->user_login );
    wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id, true );
    do_action( 'wp_login', $user->user_login );
}
```

but with no results.

Comment: Is there a technical reason why they must be the same in the database or is it only for presentation?

Comment: not really. WP allows to login using the email also, so it's not exactly a REAL issue. The problem is that this website is communicates with another web app and I have to replicate the users... I just want to keep everything in sync to avoid potential issues.

Comment: Note that bypassing WP internal functions to set user login to email address will break other WP functions like lost/reset password.  Plus email address can contain special characters like spaces percentages quotes etc.  Its best to sanitize the email address before setting to user login.

Comment: now THAT is interesting. I haven't thought about that, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try hooking in as soon as the user is created or updated.

```
<?php

function wpse_250785_sync_user_login_with_email($user_id) {
    $user = new WP_User($user_id);

    if ($user->user_login != $user->user_email) {
        $user->user_login = $user->user_email;
        wp_update_user($user);
    }
}
add_action('user_register', 'wpse_250785_sync_user_login_with_email');
add_action('profile_update', 'wpse_250785_sync_user_login_with_email');
```

> Disclaimer: Untested, but should work ;)

Comment: If I remember correctly, wp_update_user() won't update the user_login field, that's why I am running $wpdb->update().

BTW, I'll try the 'user_register' hook... I am pretty sure I have already done this but I'll try again :D

Comment: I don't see any thing in there that would prevent that from being updated. It is only the UI which doesn't give a user the means to change it.

Comment: I don't want to sound harsh, but this is right from the WP docs ( https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_user ) : 

user_login: "A string that contains the user's username for logging in. Please note that the function cannot alter this field, since WordPress does not allow usernames to be changed."

Comment: My mistake, thanks for going easy on me. I was actually referencing the developer doc here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_user/ which doesn't mention that. That's quite strange that it isn't allowed without using wpdb directly like that. Not the strangest thing in core though, I'm sure ;)

Comment: no problem, I spent two days banging my head on it, that's why I was 99.9% sure :D